# Nav disappears after resize

Tags: jquery, navigation, nav

Site in question: http://www.mtthwbsh.com

I'm building a collapsable nav for this site and have noticed that after it collapses, if you expand and retract it and enlarge the window again the nav disappears. I tried changing the display to block at my media queries but I think the jQuery is overriding it. Any idea what's causing this?

Also, I'd like the arrow to rotate 180 degrees when clicked, how would I target this? My jQuery is as follows:

```
/* toggle nav */
$("#menu-icon").on("click", function(){
$(".nav").slideToggle();
$(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(".nav").slideToggle();` appears to be leaving the nav in a `display:none;` state.  When you set tried to set the `display:block;` in your media query did you use `!important`?

**Edit**

If your screen size less than 570px needs to be toggled, then you need to make sure that at any size above 570px it will be set in CSS to display:block;

```
@media (min-width:571px) {
    .nav { display:block!important; }
}
```

This should adequately override the display property.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but then the toggle function is offset and it just toggles back after expanding.

Comment: And you have the !important declaration properly *excluded* in the smaller version's media query?

Comment: Ah, hadn't tried that, I'll give it a try in the morning and reopen the question if it doesn't work. Thanks for the input!

Comment: After looking over your stylesheet a bit more, I think that is the problem.  Your media queries are contradicting each other for this element, which will require your media queries to be mutually exclusive.  You can extend the precision of your media query by using `@media (min-width:500px) and (max-width:800px)` for example.

Comment: Yeah after trying it and failing I think that's the problem as well. I'm a bit confused on how to frame these, can you give me an idea of what you think my media queries might look like with my 3 breakpoints?

Answer (score 0):

In `style.css`, line no. 1015, media queries used for `max-width:820px`

```
@media (max-width: 820px)
```

Check these images, [Visible nav](http://i1294.photobucket.com/albums/b603/vssranganadhp/Screenshot2012-12-21at100145AM_zpsfd8a03ea.png), [Hidden nav (check css inspector)](http://i1294.photobucket.com/albums/b603/vssranganadhp/Screenshot2012-12-21at100245AM_zps7bfc505d.png)